# Отправка почты через заданное время, или как сделать рассылку между заданным интервалом.

Tags: php, время

Доброго времени препровождения всем. Вот сижу уже сутки сайт пишу, и понадобилось между заданным интервалом отправлять Email. В общем то все готово, но вот мозги после долгой и упорной работы вообще не работают... По этому я решил обратиться к народу)
В общем суть:
Есть в таблице поле '**date_start**' в него записывается текущее время, записывается раз в час (для чего объяснять не буду, долговато будет), конечно же через **time()**. Дальше надо сделать так:

```
if(($date_start+60*60)>time())
{
//проверка на интервал, каждые 10 минут и собственно отправка мыла
}
```

Вот тут проблема то и возникает, ни как не пойму как можно сделать проверку на каждые 10 минут, пока реальное время не будет больше сохраненного с + в 1 час. Помогите делему решить.На крон выводить не охота...
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: не совсем понял вопрос. при старте скрипта проверяется время, и если оно не больше определенного, то отправляется письмо? или ещё как?

Comment: да, правильно поняли и письма отсылаются каждые 10 минут

Comment: Крон, и не выпендривайтесь : )  А «дилемма» — это двойная лемма, два противоположных варинта, исключающих возможность третьего. Где у вас тут два конфликтующих варианта решения? =)

Answer (score 1):

```
while(true){
        if(($date_start + 60*60)>time()) {
            // Code..
            // Code..
            // Code..
            sleep(600) // Спим 10 минут
        }
}
```

Естественно нужно сделать в отдельном скрипте и запускать из консоли с амперсантом, что бы работало в фоновом режиме.

Comment: Было бы хорошо если бы выделялся 1 юзер, а так их выбирается не менее 10-ти, так что использую foreach... sleep наглухо убивает скрипт, надо придумать что нибудь

Answer (score 0):

```
if(($date_start + 60*60)>time()) {

}
```

Надеюсь, поле **date_start** у Вас не VARCHAR, а **TIMESTAMP** или хотя бы ***DATETIME***

Comment: нет) INT, по вопросу будут предложения?